# Перехватить нажатие клавиши назад на смартфоне

Tags: javascript

Подскажите как на javascript в браузере перехватить нажатие клавиши "Назад", на смартфоне?

upd

Задача связана со следующим:

- имеется модальные окно, оно активизируются через onlick нужно
  отловить нажатие клавиши назад
- чтобы если посетитель интуитивно
  нажмёт назад, он не вышел из сайта, а просто закрыл модальное окно

Answer (score 0):

Есть разные браузеры.
Наверно одним из вариантов будет отслеживание `url`
Например:

```js
    window.addEventListener("hashchange", function(e) {
        if(e.oldURL.length > e.newURL.length)
            alert("Нажата кнопка назад")
    });
```

```html
<div>
    <a href="#p2">Перейти</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Это никак не решает поставленной задачи. В js можно повесить обработчик на нажатие клавиши и по коду клавиши вставить обработчик, вопрос в том сработает ли это на смартфоне и какой код у клавиши назад?

Comment: Например для эскейпа: window.addEventListener("keydown", function (evt) { 
         if (evt.keyCode === 27) {

Comment: @анонимныйвопрошатель. А Вы пробовали сначала проверить код? Я вот пробовал. На телефоне сработало. У телефона в браузере по своей сути нет кнопок, пока не открыли панель клавиатуры, а соответственно и кейкодов нет. А вот отслеживание урл работает прекрасно.

Comment: Ваш метод мне не подоходит. В моём случае модальные окна активизируются через onlick, соответственно адрес не меняется, но мне нужно отловить нажатие клавиши назад -- чтобы если посетитель интуитивно нажмёт назад, он не вышел из сайта, а просто закрыл модальное окно.

Comment: @анонимныйвопрошатель в вопросе ни слова про модальные окна. Составляйте тогда правильно вопрос.

Comment: Согласно вашему методу, что произойдёт если пользователь находясь на главной странице нажмёт клавишу назад?